# Define a variable in application controller, but do not use it on pages, where content_for tag won't be present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller, impressionist

In my app I will have an ad banner, but it won't be displayed on every page. So, I've defined the ad banner in application controller:

```
before_action :set_ad_banner

def set_ad_banner
  @ad_banner = Advertising
                   .where('date_start_on <= ? AND date_end_on >= ?', Date.today, Date.today)
                   .order('RAND()')
                   .take
  impressionist(@ad_banner)
end
```

I use `impressionist` gem to see, how many times the ad has been displayed. But doing so, as it is set now, will count the impressions every time any of the pages are load, even if there is no `content_for` tag with the banner. I also tried to move the code to the view, but this code: `impressionist(@ad_banner)` doesn't work in the view. Any ideas how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: try using a helper method definition on `ApplicationHelper` rather than instance variable on ApplicationController

Comment: If I define a helper, I won't be able to use `imressionist(ad_banner)`. It gives me an error: `undefined method `impressionist' for #<#<Class:0x000000054e5cc8>:0x0000000520e680>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use

```
skip_before_action :set_ad_banner, only: [:action1, :action2]
```

to avoid invocation of this method for some actions in controllers that inherit from your `ApplicationController` where `before_action` was defined. [Guide here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

For instance:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :set_ad_banner, only: [:index]

  def index
    # some code here 
  end

  def show
    # some code here
  end
end
```

In the above example `set_ad_banner` won't be invoked before `index` action, but will be invoked before `show`.

If you don't want to invoke it at all in some controller, use `skip_before_action :set_ad_banner` without `only`/`except`.

Comment: On some controllers, I will have the ad banner and on some other controllers, I won't. So setting controller names in `only:` array won't be easy.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi There are actions names in `only` (index, show, etc.), not controllers names. And `skip_before_action` is usually used in descendants of controller where `before_action` was defined. So, in some controllers you will use it, and in some - won't. Check the example with LoginsController in [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).